# How to display all eslint warnings of the whole project in Atom?

Tags: node.js, webpack, atom-editor, eslint

Currently my client-side project is build by webpack. Linting the project is part of the build process. All lint warnings/errors in the project are displayed in the console.

When I open a file in Atom, the warnings in that file are shown. But only the warnings of all open files can be displayed. I want to see all warnings in the whole project so I can click on them and solve them quickly.

I was wondering if there is such a solution in Atom. Any suggestions?

I'm using the following Atom packages:

- [linter](https://github.com/steelbrain/linter), version: 1.11.18
- [linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint), version: 8.0.0

And the following npm package:

- [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint), version 3.12.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported to lint the whole project with `linter-eslint`.

But you can use [atom-terminal-panel](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal-panel) to manually lint the whole project with `eslint`. The `atom-terminal-panel` will display the eslint errors/warnigns with clickable file links.

Comment: I needed to reduce the output of webpack, otherwise the Atom plugin gets stuck. My webpack devServer stats flags: { assets: false, chunks: false, colors: false }. Any idea why the Atom plugin can't recognize the file names, when colors are used in the output of webpack? Currently it only works without using colors. The Atom plugin then adds some colors using the terminal-commands.json config file.

Comment: You can use custom [format](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api.html#executeonfiles()) option with `eslint-loader` to limit the errors/warnings.

Comment: @Thaadikkaaran - how do you use eslint within atom-terminal-panel?

Comment: @nishant you have to run eslint on `atom-terminal-panel` either as command or gulp task or webpack